# How do I start a community that isn't listed?

Tags: helper

How do I start my own community on this app? Is it possible? I noticed there isn't a community for Art enthusiast's.

Comment: While offtopic: https://area51.stackexchange.com/ for new and https://stackexchange.com/sites for existing stacks (art: https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is looking to start a new StackExchange site